# Handling core dump condition

Tags: c++

I have some simple code (This is a much smaller example of the bigger code I have):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <list>

// List of blocks
std::list<struct Block> Blocks;

class ObjInfo
{
private:
  int size;
public:
  ObjInfo(int size){this->size = size;}
  int get_size() {return size;}
};

struct Block
{
  // name of the block
  int x;
  // Actual variable stack
  std::unordered_map <int, ObjInfo*> objinfostack;
};

int main()
{
int x = 2;
while( x >= 0 )
{
  Block b;
  b.x = x;
  b.objinfostack.insert(std::make_pair(x, new ObjInfo(4)));
  --x;
  Blocks.push_front(b);
}
for(std::list<struct Block>::iterator i = Blocks.begin(); i!=Blocks.end(); ++i)
{
  std::cout << "here: " << i->objinfostack[1]->get_size() << '\n';
}

return 0;

}
```

**Quick explanation on what is going on in the code:**

Notice the following line leads to the `seg fault`:

```
std::cout << "here: " << i->objinfostack[1]->get_size() << '\n';
```

It happens because of the invalid access:

```
i->objinfostack[1]
```

As I'll get something like this in the `Blocks` list:

```
i->objinfostack[2], i->objinfostack[1]
```

My question is how can I handle such invalid conditions.

Comment: I believe it creates pairs like this: (key): x and (value):Object, in this case `objObjInfo`

Comment: The question to you is this -- did you realize that there is no key value of `1` in the map?  Or did you think there was a key value of `1`?  If you did know there was no key value of `1`, do you know what the map class does when the key doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, I realize that there is no key value 1 in the map. I just don't know how to handle such condition.

Comment: @Ruturaj Easy -- Don't use `[]`.

Comment: No, but let's say the condition in this hypothetical example is for the block-2 and i just want to ignore it in the block-1?

Comment: Then the code is ill-written, plain and simple.  You are letting the map insert the key by using `operator []` automatically, and that is the wrong behavior for your use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how can I handle such invalid condition

You handle such conditions by not using `operator []` for the map if you are not sure if the entry exists or not.  The `operator []` will automatically insert an entry into the map if the key value does not exist.  You cannot change this behavior -- that's how the `operator []` works when the key doesn't exist as it will create a `nullptr` for the value, since that is the zero-initial value for a pointer type.

Instead, you should use `std::unordered_map::find()` to test if the key exists instead of using `[]`, and use the iterator returned if it is not `end()`:

```
auto iter = i->objinfostack.find(1);
if ( iter != i->objinfostack.end())
    std::cout << "here: " << iter->second->get_size() << '\n';
```

---

If you really wanted to insert an item if the key doesn't exist, and you want the object to point somewhere valid, then you need to make an explicit call to `insert()`:

```
i->objinfostack.insert({1, new ObjInfo(4)});
```

What will happen is that insert always checks to see if the key entry exists, and if it doesn't exist, a new entry is inserted into the map. So the above code will always create an entry if it doesn't exist, and will leave the entry alone if it already existed.

The one issue with this however is that a memory leak will occur if the object already exists, since `new` would be called without the corresponding delete.  To address this issue, you can either

1) change your map to store an RAII type as the value type (`std::vector<ObjInfo>`  `std::shared_ptr`, std::unique_ptr`, for example), or

2) Detect that an insertion didn't occur, and thus `delete` the allocated object separately.

```
auto new_ptr = new ObjInfo(4);
auto pr = i->objinfostack.insert({1, new_ptr});
if (!pr.second) // insert didn't happen
    delete new_ptr;
```

But of course this gets cumbersome, and probably the easiest thing to do is use `std::map::find()` first, and allocate / insert into the map if the entry isn't found.

So take your pick --

1) if the entry doesn't exist, then do nothing (use find()) or

2) if the entry doesn't exist, create an entry that has a valid `ObjInfo` (use `insert()`, but heed the caveats expressed above).

---

The bottom line is never use the map `operator []` unconditionally unless you are certain you want to create a new key with a default constructed or zero-initialized value automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The index is invalid, hence the crash:

```
i->objinfostack[1]
```

The first Block added to the list, will add an entry into map for:

```
objinfostack[2] = {2, somePointer}
```

The second Block will be added for:

```
objinfostack[1] = {1, somePointer}
```

So when you walk the list, you'll end up accessing index [1] on a Block that only has the index [2] inserted into it. As a result, the block will be invalid. If you did something like this, the problem would go away:

```
for(std::list<Block>::iterator i = Blocks.begin(); i!=Blocks.end(); ++i)
{
  std::cout << "Block....\n";
  for(auto& val : i->objinfostack)
  {
    std::cout << '[' << val.first << "] " << val.second->get_size() << '\n';
  }
}
```